Truncated Karhunen Loeve Transforms. Can they be rotated to maximize smoothness of elements?
Background
The Karhunen-Loeve-Transform (KLT) is a famous transform in the pattern recognition communities.  Consider a n dimensional multivariate signal of $k$ samples represented as a matrix $x \in \mathbb R^{k\times n}$.
Covariance matrix $$C = (x-\mu)^t(x-\mu) \in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$$
Where $\mu\in \mathbb R^{k\times n}$ is mean value of $x$ along rows.
Now the singular value decomposition (SVD) will find linear combinations of the n dimensions , subspaces , according to variation. The vector of the largest singular value will in some sense be the "direction" in which the largest co-variation can be found.
The SVD of a symmetric matrix such as the covariance matrix above can be written as:
$$C = U\Sigma U^t$$
Without loss of generality and by convention we can assume that the $\Sigma$ is sorted according to size of diagonal elements.
Furthermore we can define a minimal norm-loss $n_1$ dimension truncated KLT to be the one which preserves all the largest $n_1$ $\Sigma$ diagonal values and sets the rest to $0$. Once the $n-n_1$ rows of U corresponding to the 0ed out elements can be removed.
Question
Now to my question. Can I somehow find an optimal "rotation" in some sense, let us call it $R, s.t. R^tR = I$ of the subspace of such a truncated KLT if what I want to get is the vectors contained in $UR(x-\mu)$ to be as "smooth" as possible. For example by a discrete difference scheme, represented by a matrix $D$.
I suspect this will boil down to a matrix optimization of the form
$$R_{opt} = \min_R \| DUR(x-\mu) \| s.t. R^tR = I $$
But the constraint seems to break linearity.
Does anyone have any ideas of how to devise a practical solver?

So you want a rotation of the subspace spanned by the top eigenvectors of $C$ into itself? Let’s minimize the square norm instead.  Then it can be reformulated as finding a rotation $R$ to minimize the expected square norm of $D R U (x - \mu)$ instead.  (Where $U$ has been culled to contain only the top eigenvectors of $C$.) This rotation must map the eigenvectors of $D^\ast D$ to those of $U \Sigma U^{\ast}$.

Got the order reversed: the rotation must map the eigenvectors of $U \Sigma U^{\ast}$ to those of $D^\ast D$. (Actually, $R^{-1} D^{\ast} D R$ must commute with $U \Sigma U^{\ast}$.)

Yes minimizing square norm instead of norm is okay. I may have gotten a transpose or order of multiplication wrong, not quite sure. The spectrum of my D operator should be all 1:s except possibly one 0 eigenvalue for the mean value, sum ( discrete approximation of integral ), all ones vector. For practical purposes I suppose we can set all the "surviving" sigmas to 1. In practice I might assign more bits to store them with greater accuracy in my application, but their actual magnitudes should not matter for the purpose of rotating the basis.
